# Commandline overwrites itself when the commands get too long

Tags: linux, debian, putty

I'm using PuTTY to log into a Debian server. I have this odd problem that when a command I'm typing gets too long, it doesn't wraparound and start a new line. Instead, it starts at the beginning of the *same* line and starts to overwrite the prompt and then the beginning of the command.

The command will run just fine, but it is really annoying, I'm assuming there is some setting that would fix this for me?

Comment: Restore down (un-maximize) the window and maximize it again
Worked fine

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've seen this behavior when you resize the Putty window while another command is running since bash doesn't get the signal telling it the window has resized.

If this is the problem adding:

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

should make it go away.

Answer (score 85):

I've just solved this myself.

It was just some color escapes in the PS1 command prompt:

```
LTGREEN="\033[40;1;32m"
LTBLUE="\033[40;1;34m"
CLEAR="\033[0m"
LIGHT_GRAY="\033[40;1;33m"
export PS1="$LTGREEN\u$LTBLUE@\h:$LIGHT_GRAY\w$CLEAR ❯ "
```

The issue is that the color literals are not enclosed in brackets. Placing escaped brackets around them fixes the issue entirely:

```
LTGREEN="\[\033[40;1;32m\]"
LTBLUE="\[\033[40;1;34m\]"
CLEAR="\[\033[0m\]"
LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[40;1;33m\]"
export PS1="$LTGREEN\u$LTBLUE@\h:$LIGHT_GRAY\w$CLEAR ❯ "
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was fighting this for a few days now. You made my day and you have upvote!

Comment: don't forget to use double quotes for your PS1 variable

Comment: It was done earlier, then when I learned how to write PS1, I thought it was of no use and removed it. Made my day too

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my problem in all the cli softwares including iterm3.

Comment: How did you ever figure this out and why is this needed? Does it need to be around each colour literal (as you have done) or can it wrap multiple colour literals at once?

Comment: In my testing, it seems it is acceptable to wrap runs of multiple colour escapes (including bolds, resets and other ANSI escape sequences) in just a single pair of escaped brackets (`\[...\]`). It is not necessary to wrap every single escape individually.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions I don't remember exactly how I figured it out, but after a long time searching I think I gave up. Then later, happened to land on a discrepancy in my color literals and other examples on the web. I used the new format I found, then, the other problem disappeared, and I had the aha moment.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
eval $(resize)
```

ََََََََََ

Comment: it worked on PUTTY. I was connecting Ubuntu 12.04 with putty. Thanks.

Comment: This works for me only when I type it manually, when I put this inside .bashrc it does not work, any ideas? thank you.

Comment: @WakanTanka Try echo $(resize). You'll see that resize wants to set two variables and then export the information (e.g. COLUMNS=109; LINES=37; export COLUMNS LINES;). This information depends on the *current* size of your window. Running the command for the current window requires eval.

Answer (score 8):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. (Or maybe <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> - <kbd>something</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> anyway.) If I remember rightly this reruns the code to figure out your terminal size and adjusts accordingly.

Comment: Here's the bash reference if you're interested, Ctrl+l clears the screen. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Moving.html

Answer (score 2):

```
Ctrl-l
```

Ctrl-l works.  I guess the putty needed to

Answer (score 1):

This [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19265/20085) worked for me:
Add the following snippet to your `.bashrc`:

```
if [ $(tty) == '/dev/ttyS0' ]; then
  trap resize DEBUG
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This one helps me to resolve this after searching lot of places.

```
PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\t\[\e[m\]-\[\e[0;32m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\[\e[0;36m\]\h\[\e[m\]:\[\e[0;23m\]\w\[\e[m\e[0;32m\]\$\[\e[m\]'
```

Enclosing enclosing each of the colour escape sequences in escaped square brackets.

Answer (score -3):

Nothing to do with putty its a "bash"ism.

Its quite useful once you are used to it, but, if it bothers you you can switch to "ksh" which does something different with long command lines (not sure what on Debian!)

Comment: No, not in putty, usually it wraps the command. Its another thing, that sometimes occurs.

Comment: Readline (which Bash uses for interactive line editing) does have a `horizontal-scroll-mode` option, but it doesn't entirely match OP's reported symptoms.